# How to DISABLE multiple photo select on iOS from <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">

Tags: ios, html, image

On my website how to disable multiple photo select on iOS from

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

I don't want user to select more than 1 photo from photo gallery.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

#### The "multiple" attribute

File inputs only accept a single file by default. That's why there's a boolean attribute called "multiple" which makes the input admit more than one file.

```html
<!-- This input admits just one image -->

    <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" name="img">

<!-- And this one will admit more than one image -->

    <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" name="img" multiple>
```

---

You can find information about this attribute in the following websites:

> https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_multiple.asp

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple